# how to get back old modified user name and date in Sharepoint 2010 document library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, powershell

Is is possible to revert sharepoint back with old modified user and modified date information?

Even restoring version history changes modified user and date.

For ex:

**my file in sharepoint 2010 look like:**

```
   Name  modified by       Modified

    ABC        johan       2012-10-12

And I made certain changes and now it is

   Name       modified by    Modified 

    ABC        Kirstine       2013-12-09
```

Can I revert my file back to previous metadata with previous modified user and date?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change it using the following in PowerShell:

```
$w = get-SPWeb http://SITEURL
$l = $w.Lists["LISTNAME"]
$i = $l.GetItemById(IDOFDOC)
$i["Modified"]="2012-10-12"
$i.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

Comment: This is the case, when you know last modified date, but what if we don't know the last modified date and last modified person?

Comment: If you've versioning turned on then you can get the information from `SPListItem.Versions`. If not then SharePoint has no info that can help you.