# Lost "modified by" name - Moving File

Tags: 2010, versioning, move, modified

I needed to move some files from one document store to another (I need to maintain version history as well as who made modifications).

I moved the file by standard explorer view drag and drop method (I checked to ensure that both folders had versioning etc).
Files moved with no issue and version history is intact....however Modified by = Gareth Miskelly (my name), not the actual users name who made the versions...

Can anyone advise how I can get this information back?

I have a backup from last night which I tried restoring....but unfortunately this does the same (i.e. modified by column = administrator for every value)

[image: Original files after move]
[image: Restore files]

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84681/how-to-get-back-old-modified-user-name-and-date-in-sharepoint-2010-document-libr